# How to stream video and music over LAN?

Tags: lan, streaming

What I have:

- An old laptop with an external harddrive via USB
- A wireless router

What I want to achieve:

- Stream video and music to

  - PC
  - Mac
  - iPad
  - Xbox360 (it's ok if it doesn't work with xbox360, this is just a bonus)

My question:

- Which OS on the laptop would be the best for this purpose? Windows 7 or a Linux server?
- Do I need any streaming software on the server, or just simply *share* the harddrive?

Ideally, I would like to just host the media files on the harddrive, and use native programs (iTunes on Mac/iPad, WMP on PC) to play music/videos, is this possible?

If I really need to install some software to do this, what can I use?

Comment: i think subsonic will do what you want. its free.

Comment: Please consider rephrasing this question as it's very open ended and not really seeking to learn about the technology involved.

Comment: @KronoS, Thanks, but how can I make this question more clear? I just want to know what's the best way to stream music/videos to my PC/Mac/iPad at home.

Comment: Consider looking at [this meta post](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5372/how-do-i-ask-a-question-that-may-require-recommending-software) on how to ask questions that will end up recommending software.  It should be a good guide on what you can do to better improve the question.

Comment: @KronoS, awesome, that's a great post.

Comment: Either OS can do it. However, you may want to consider buying a NAS for your media, then Google a phrase like Media Player (I use the WD one). This way, all my devices (phone/PC/TV) can connect to it. However, new TV's can connect direct to media players but you need to read the TV requirements to know if you need NAS/Windows/Linux etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html).

See the [streams related page on their website](http://www.videolan.org/streaming-features.html).

It is open source software.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I simply user file sharing and open/play the files with standard software like MCE and WMP on Windows clients. VLC and other standard media players will work too, then map to the shares over the network.

For the Mac you’d need to look at http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1568 as well and XBOX please user http://www.wikihow.com/Share-Files-from-Windows-PC-to-Xbox-360

I’m assuming you’re hosting the files on the Windows machine?

Comment: That is part of my question, I don't know if I should host on a Windows machine, since I'm sharing cross platform. Will a Linux server be a better choice?

Comment: It’s up to you, are you familiar with networking with Linux, especially between NT machines?

Comment: No, not really. But if it can do want I want (streaming to PC/Mac/iOS), I wouldn't mind learning it. Actually I would prefer that way, since I won't need a cumbersome desktop UI on the old laptop.

Answer (score 1):

The 360 has this function native, in the media center, if I'm not mistaken.

Now, having the feature and using the feature, with Microsoft those are always two different things.  If you are using a pre-7 OS you will have difficulty perhaps, but 7 and later should have Media Center installed; and media recognized by WMC on the laptop will theoretically be visible from the Xbox, assuming they are both on the network.  If the media is not already added to WMP you will have to manually add it to WMC (or WMP), I believe (again, going on memory).  One major downside is that 360 has a very limited codec library that can not be manually expanded, meaning you have to wait for updates to their software, but this is generally only a problem with video.

If you can't tell, I've had a lot of problems getting this to work in the past, but there have been a few computers I've been successfully able to stream to my 360.

As far as the other devices, the Mac and iPad, I am not sure, but it looks like those have already been answered.